# CiviCRM Blank Screen and Error on Dashboard

Tags: error

I am trying to install CiviCRM on wordpress hosted by our own server. The install would seem to have installed. However, we get a blank screen on the dashboard after install. I have reinstalled it a few times but get the same thing, a blank screen. I enabled debugging and this is the error I get:

Warning: include(/volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US//%%E6/E65/E656EDCD%%wordpress.tpl.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1273 Warning: include(): Failed opening '/volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US//%%E6/E65/E656EDCD%%wordpress.tpl.php' for inclusion (include_path='/volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/flexmailer/:/volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/legacycustomsearches/:/volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/ckeditor4/:/volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/recaptcha/:/volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/financialacls/:/volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/eventcart/:/volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/greenwich/:.:/volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm:/volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages:/volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/volume1/web_packages/wordpress/ in /volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1273

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I had this issue when my templates_c folder didn't have the correct permissions on my server.

On my bitnami server, I had to do this ([source](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress-multisite/administration/understand-file-permissions/#:%7E:text=Bitnami%20applies%20the%20following%20default%20permissions%20to%20WordPress,The%20wp-config.php%20file%20is%20configured%20with%20permissions%20640.)):

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon TARGET
sudo find TARGET -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find TARGET -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo chmod 640 TARGET/wp-config.php
```